# JavaScript to trigger PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Is it possible to have an input text box such that when a person types something and presses submit or enter, I can trigger PHP to submit that data to a database without leaving the page (hence the JavaScript)?

Comment: Read up on [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [spelling](http://www.spelling.hemscott.net/), and [grammar](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/).

Comment: this has got to be a troll? Flagged. Sorry if I'm misinterpreting the situation.

Comment: +1, not sure why you were getting -1 votes - this is an honest question from somebody who just needs to entry level ajax help.

Comment: @Josh: addressed at least the latter two.

Comment: @Matthew: you probably got -1 (-2 now) because of the lazy spelling and grammar. English as a second language is one thing, but that doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: have you tried searching SO first before asking?... this question is really being asked repeatedly...

Comment: thanks matthew M i am in a rush and don't have time to spell u guys are making a deal about it i just want to know how to do this. lol not get instructions on how to spell.

Comment: @Matthew: 90% of barrier to getting proper help is effective communication of the problem you are having or topic you are trying to understand.

Comment: @Matthew: I translate your comment as "I don't have enough respect for you to pay attention to how I communicate."

Comment: @Matthew Then why are you asking us for help? If you don't respect us enough to pay attention to how you communicate, then how is it you respect us enough to want our opinion(s)?

Comment: okay everyone calm down i just wanted to know how to do something i didn't ask for a lecture on spelling. Matthew Morrison answered it with no problem why does every else care. Besides the question is already answered

Comment: We just care... that's why you are getting up/down votes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going to want to look into something called AJAX.  I won't add any code here because there are [thousands of excellent tutorials out there](http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+tutorial) that will be much more thorough than I can  type here.  I would recommend using the [jQuery Javascript library](http://jquery.com/) to help out.

Comment: Thanks again i just saw a tutorial on W3C and its kinda easy

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible. Here's [an example](http://ucfirefly.com/heatmap/index.php) of the sort of technique you want.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by using a `<form>` tag with you textbox and submit button inside.

```
<form name="input" action="do_something.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="Value" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This isn't what he's asking for - he said, "without leaving the page".

Comment: Oops. Guess I should read the question more carefully next time.